# Assign date/time from JSON in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I noticed, when receive data from my Server/API (in this case asp.net core 3.1) Angular assigns a string to the date target field instead of actually "converting" it into a Date.

As far as I can tell for now, it's not a problem with asp.net core or the "server side".

I did the following Test and either I understand something completly wrong here or the JSON parser is broken...(i hope not)?

```
//The target interface for testing
export interface DateTesting
{
  aText: string;
  aDate: Date;
}

//For testing
let input: DateTesting = { aText: "Hello World!", aDate: new Date() };
console.log(JSON.stringify(input));   //-> outputs the "input" object as JSON

let json = JSON.stringify(input);     //-> {"aText":"Hello World!","aDate":"2022-07-12T12:01:46.498Z"}
let output: DateTesting = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(output);                  //-> outputs the object "output"
console.log(typeof output.aDate);     //-> is a string! Looks like the parser is broken??
console.log(output.aDate.getDay());   //-> Results in an Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Invalid time"
```

So, what am I missing here? Can i tell the parser anyhow to assign a date and not a string when the target type is a Date?

I also don't think that the correct solution is to do "Date.parse(whatsoever)" for each date field, also because I want to keep the whole thing as "generic" as possible.

I'm using Angular 12.1.2

Comment: This is definitely not an angular problem, more a problem of what `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` does with date "objects".

Comment: It seems that `JSON.stringify` calls the method `toISOString()` when doing its thing, that why you get a string instead of a `Date` object. There are some utils that let you stringify an object while preserving the object. [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-date) should do the trick.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I can't convert each field of each object separately. I query the api using "HttpClient" (@angular/common/http) and I already have a (incorrectly converted) object in the body of the response. `this.http.post<DateTesting>("http://127.0.0.1/xyz", data).subscribe(resp => ...)`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have used your suggestion as a "workaround" for now... By changing the http body back into a string and parse it again with 'json-stringify-date'. Works so far, unfortunately not really the solution I wanted to have.
Maybe I can figure out how to prevent http-get/post from parsing automatically, so I don't have to convert it back.

Comment: Apart from @dariosicly's answer I don't know more about that, sorry. Maybe a total approach change would solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i tell the json parser anyhow to assign a date and not a string when
> the target type is a Date?

Yes, you can if you use the `JSON.parse` method with the optional [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?retiredLocale=it) argument. From the documentation *if a reviver is specified, the value computed by parsing is transformed before being returned. Specifically, the computed value and all its properties (beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself) are individually run through the reviver.* So in your specific case you can specify your `aDate` property and return your date string as a new `Date` object instead of a string like below:

```
let output: DateTesting = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
    //instead of a string it returns a Date object
    if (key === 'aDate') return new Date(value);
    return value;     // return the unchanged property value for other keys.
});
console.log(typeof output.aDate);     //-> is a Date object
console.log(output.aDate.getDay()); //ok it works and returns a number
```

Comment: I am already familiar with this approach. Unfortunately, it is not a good fix for me, since my classes and functions where this would be applied are then no longer generic. (e.g. API queries) What I was trying to say with `Can i tell the json parser anyhow to assign a date and not a string when the target type is a Date?` was if there is a "global" way to do this, i.e. settings that then apply to the parser in general. (Similar as if I would define an own JSON converter in asp.net core).

Comment: @MartinM43 The problem is that the json deserialization from a string value normally returns a string as from spec, while in this case it should return a `Date` object. You can create a class constructor  and then pass the json as an argument and inside it doing something similar to what I proposed, unless there is some builtin angular mechanism that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a generic approach that covers any Date property in your interfaces you can use this Decorator

```
    import {map} from "rxjs/operators";

    let dateRegex = new RegExp(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/); // yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
    
    /**
     * Automatically transforms all dates in json in defined regex format to Date entity
     */
    export function TransformDate(target, key: string, descriptor: any) {
      const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
      descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        return originalMethod.apply(this, args).pipe(
          map((obj) => convertDatesInObject(obj))
        );
      }
      return descriptor;
    }
    
    
    const isDate = (s) => dateRegex.test(s);
    
    function convertDatesInObject(obj): any {
      if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
        return obj;
      }
      if (isDate(obj)) {
        return new Date(obj) as any;
      }
      if (obj instanceof Array) {
        return obj.map((n: any) => convertDatesInObject(n)) as any;
      }
      if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== {}) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
          obj[k] = convertDatesInObject(obj[k]);
        });
        return obj;
      }
      return obj;
    }
```

And then you can just put this decorator to any function calling your API and all string that match the defined regexp will be then parsed to Date object automatically.

```
@TransformDate
getData$(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.httpService.getRequest<Data[]>('yourURL');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to write an interceptor, which will automatically convert all date strings into Date objects.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    this.postProcessDates(event.body);
                    return event;
                }
            })
        );
    }

    /**
     * PostProcessing Dates
     * Converting UTC to Local Date
     * Date must be in ISO 8601 format
     */
    private postProcessDates(obj: any): any {
        if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
            return obj;
        }

        if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
            return obj;
        }

        for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
            const value = obj[key];
            const iso8601 = /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?(([+-]\d\d:\d\d)|Z)?$/;

            if (iso8601.test(value) === true) {
                obj[key] = new Date(value);
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                this.postProcessDates(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```